# Flutter duplicated files packages and dependencies

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I took over a project from another developer i notice that there is too many files (.flutter-plugin)(.flutter-plugins-dependencies)(.packages)

How to fix that or if i deleted the numbered ones will cause any issues?

Screenshot below

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to fix that or if i deleted the numbered ones will cause any issues?

Comment: Try : "flutter clean" then "flutter run" on the terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you on Mac or Windows? I had the issue on my MacBook and realised that it was because I was syncing my Desktop and Documents folder to iClouds.

My flutter files were inside of Documents and they were syncing to iCloud every time I saved my code. Thats when I realised the file duplication.

You can disable syncing your Documents to iCloud with the guide here: https://appletoolbox.com/how-to-stop-icloud-syncing-desktop-folders/

Comment: Thanks, i think i will change my project location because i need to keep my desktop and document sync with iCloud

Comment: just add .nosync to your project folder. Should be fine. Doesn't matter where your project is located